# android code margin only for text

Tags: java, android

I want to set margin only for text inside code, and not the background resource. How will I go about doing this?

The background is a 9patch image.

Here is a snippet of my code.

```
    StringBuffer sBuffer = new StringBuffer();
    sBuffer.append(sent + ":\n");
    sBuffer.append(username + ":\n");
    sBuffer.append(message + "\n");

    RelativeLayout layout = new RelativeLayout(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams topParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    topParams.setMargins(10, 10, 10, 10);
    layout.setLayoutParams(topParams);

    TextView valueTV = new TextView(this);
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    if (username.equals(friend.userName)) {
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT);
        valueTV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_bub_left_blue);
        params.setMargins(20, 10, 10, 10);

    } else {
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
        valueTV.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.chat_bub_right_green);
        params.setMargins(60, 10, 10, 30);
    }

    valueTV.setLayoutParams(params);
    valueTV.setText(sBuffer);
```

Comment: I think you forget to assign the layoutParams for your TextView : valueTV.setLayoutParams(params);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have you tried text padding? Here's how:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setPadding%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int%29

Comment: I tried this, but it gives me the same results. It gives padding to the text and to the background image

Comment: This helped -> valueTV.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the parameters to the textview.
You can do it like this, assuming that you want to use the margin parameters in your code.

```
valueTV.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: I do have that in my code. The problem isn't setting it, the problem is only giving text margin and not the background image as well